# New variable in long format data based on timepoint in R

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I cannot seem to find the answer on how to create a new (e.g.) grouping variable in a long format data frame or tibble based some row operations in R

Using this example:

```
toosimpledataset_long <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='subject sex Timepoint measurement measurement2 
      1    M       T01         7.9          1.9       
      1    M       T02        12.3          NA
      1    M       T03        10.7          1.7
      1    M       T04         9.7          1.7
      2    F       T01         6.3          1.3
      2    F       T02        10.6          1.6
      2    F       T03        11.1           NA
      2    F       T04        12.5          1.7
      3    F       T01         5.5           NA
      3    F       T02          NA          1.1
      3    F       T03        13.8          1.8
      3    F       T04        15.7          1.7 
      4    M       T01        10.5          1.5
      4    M       T02        13.4          1.4
      4    M       T03        12.4          1.4
      4    M       T04        11.3          1.9    
                           ')
```

I would like to create

1. one factor-variable that indexes whether each subject's value at *T02* is e.g. <= 11 in the **measurement** variable
2. and a factor-variable which indexes wheteher the percentage of change from *T01* to *T04* is smaller than 50%

To be able to use these factor-variables as grouping variable, e.g. for plotting in ggplot, the values have to be filled in every row of each subject (I think).

Therefore, the correct dataset should look like this:

```
subject  sex Timepoint measurement measurement2 responder_crit responder_percentage
1          M       T01         7.9          1.9              0                    1         
1          M       T02        12.3           NA              0                    1
1          M       T03        10.7          1.7              0                    1
1          M       T04         9.7          1.7              0                    1
2          F       T01         6.3          1.3              1                    0
2          F       T02        10.6          1.6              1                    0
2          F       T03        11.1           NA              1                    0
2          F       T04        12.5          1.7              1                    0   
3          F       T01         5.5           NA              NA                   0
3          F       T02          NA          1.1              NA                   0
3          F       T03        13.8          1.8              NA                   0
3          F       T04        15.7          1.7              NA                   0    
4          M       T01        10.5          1.5              0                    1
4          M       T02        13.4          1.4              0                    1
4          M       T03        12.4          1.4              0                    1
4          M       T04        11.3          1.9              0                    1
```

Not sure if reshaping is the stadard way to doing something like this. Unfortunately, the real dataset very is large and very messy. Reshaping does not work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset for certain timepoints within a `mutate` call:

```
toosimpledataset_long %>% 
  group_by(subject) %>% 
  mutate(
    responder_crit = measurement[Timepoint == 'T02'] >= 11,
    responder_percentage = (measurement[Timepoint == 'T04'] / measurement[Timepoint == 'T01']) < 1.5
  )
```

I don't get quite the same for `responder_crit`, but I don't understand how you get only one NA in your example there.

Comment: It looks that `responder_crit` is just `+(measurement <= 11)` without any grouping.

Comment: Sorry, I had uploaded an incorrect table, hence the nonsensical responder_crit variable. I have editeted it, but you got it anyway!!! Thanks so much,  this really helps! I'll be sure to check out dplyr commands. Cool website btw. R is great